# Survey data: long to wide including question numbering

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reshape my survey dataframe from long to wide. The current dataframe looks like this, where a second occurrence of a name refers to a answer on a secon question, and so forth:

```
Name | A | B | C | D | E |
Bob    X   
Ted        X
Chris      X
Bob            X
Ted                     X
Chris  X
```

Ideally, my df would look like this:

```
Name | Q1 | Q2 |
Bob    A    C
Ted    B    E    
Chris  B    A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `stack` then create the `pivot` key with `groupby` `cumcount`

```
s = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index()
out = s.assign(key = s.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1).pivot('Name','key','level_1').add_prefix('Q')
Out[17]: 
key   Q1 Q2
Name       
Bob    A  C
Chris  B  A
Ted    B  E
```